# Generating ActiveSync sync/fetch commands load on an Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, activesync

I'm developing an Exchange plugin that may effect ActiveSync operations. 
I am now looking for a quick way to generate a high load of sync/fetch operations that will simulate multiple ISO/Android devices which are tring to sync and fetch emails from multiple mailboxes.

It was able to load 10,000 mailbox to my Exchange 2010 SP1 server, but it seems I can not sync any of those mailbox when sending a request with SyncKey: 1 and Class: Email. It always fails with an object not found status code, even when the mailbox is filled with messages.

For some reason, as soon as I configured a real IOS/Android Exchange client with a specific mailbox, suddenly It is possible to sync this mailbox.

Is there an easy way to configure this initial state on all of those 10,000 mailboxes, so I would be able to sync them all later with a simple Sync command (SyncKey: 1  and Class: Email) ? Or do you have any other idea how to generate this kind of load?

**Here is the response I'm getting, when sending a Sync command with SyncKey = 0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Sync xmlns="http://synce.org/formats/airsync_wm5/airsync">
    <Status xmlns="http://synce.org/formats/airsync_wm5/airsync">8</Status>
</Sync>
```

Comment: Have you done a FolderSync first? You can't just go directly to the Sync command - you most likely have to start with a sequence of Provision, FolderSync and then Sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy way to do this; clients basically must go through the following:

1. Run `FolderSync` w. `SyncKey=0` to get the overall folder structure.
2. Run `Sync` w. `SyncKey=0` on each of those folders to get it's contents.

Specifically, you always have to return the previous `SyncKey` for any operation on a given folder, thus forcing you to do things sequentially. Basically, [[MS-ASCMD]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299441) is the place to look.

(You might also have to send a `Provision`-command to the server to get started. Check out [[MS-ASPROV]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299443) for the details.)

So basically, I think you'd be better off using an existing client that either implements a simpler API or proxies to something more workable. You could look at [DAVMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), which is a IMAP→EAS proxy - thus you'd "only" have to implement something in IMAP...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the sync key is 1? When I have worked with Exchange servers and active sync the first real sync key is always something like `000000000{388899F6-C5A1-4903-B638-1F5021C556BE}0`

Get the synckey by running sync command with `synckey = 0`

Comment: I've also tried to send a SyncKey=0 but I'm also getting the following response:  <?xml version="1.0"?><Sync><Status>8</Status></Sync>

Comment: Status code 8 from Sync means "object not found". See the docs for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675457%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: It seems like you are not sending  a <CollectionId>

Comment: you get the collectionId from doing the foldersync